# Parsing X.509 ASN.1 binary data

Tags: algorithm, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

According to [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1075.3914&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article, we can see the following in the paper:

[image]

1. Can we treat the above X.509 grammar as this: the SEQUENCE and SET elements are non-terminals, while the rest are terminals. We could therefore also rewrite the grammar as follows:

   ```
    Certificate = A
    signatureAlgorithm = c
    signature = d
    ToBeSigned = T

    S => A | AA    ; either a single or many Certificate elements
    A => TA | Tcd  ; TA supports TA, TTA, TTTA, so we can have multiple T non-terminals (cd are non-terminals: signartureAlgorithm and signature which come at the end)
    T = vs...e     ; all of the elements from version, serialNumber, ..., extensions
   ```

What would be the best way to transform the above into a more usable grammar with standard letters: can we treat all ToBeSigned elements as simply as non-terminals: vertor = v, serialNumber = s, etc?

2. According to the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/chomsky_classification_of_grammars.htm), which kind of grammar is this? Is it a regular grammar?

Comment: Interesting article.  I love this line: `"Unforgeability relies on the O-SNARK knowledge soundness of Pinocchio..."`.  2) I don't believe X.509 is a "regular" ("type-3") grammer, because it doesn't sound like it has "a production of the form `X → a or X → aY`".  4) I don't believe there's any "One True Answer" - it sounds like a matter of opinion and/or a topic for an extended essay ;)

Comment: I gave this a close vote because it needs more focus. To answer these with enough detail to make sense  would need a few chapters.

Comment: `I would like to get more knowledge about parsing stuff` get the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)

Comment: Modified a question considerably and only left the actual grammar, what is it and how to write it into a more "grammar-like" form; removed all the parsing stuff.

Comment: This question is about technology used *in* [tag:compiler-construction], but it isn't *about*  [tag:compiler-construction].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we treat the above X.509 grammar as this: the `SEQUENCE` and `SET` elements are non-terminals, while the rest are terminals?

I'd say that's basically a category error. But even if it were not, it's not a particularly useful model for what ASN.1 types are.

A *terminal* is an atomic unit with no grammatical structure. (At least, that's one intuition for a terminal. In Chomskyian context-free grammars, the definition is even simpler: it's a symbol which does not appear on the left-hand side of any production.) But many of the types in that extract do have definitions in the X.509 documents, so they certainly aren't terminals. Arguably, `BIT STRING` is a terminal, since it's more or less a primitive ASN.1 type, but in concrete grammars in the BER and DER profiles, it's actually a non-terminal, too.

"ASN" is an abbreviation for "Abstract Syntax Notation"; avoiding the ambiguity of English noun phrases, it is a notation for writing *abstract syntaxes*. ASN.1 abstracts away from the concrete syntax. It's a way of focussing on the structural interrelationships inside a complex data object without getting bogged down in the real-world mechanics of parsing or generating sentences. In that sense, it's more or less the mirror image of a Chomskyian grammar; Chomsky's goal (in the famous paper which gave rise to the hierarchy) was to abstract away from the semantics, leaving only the mechanics of parsing and generating sentences. It's in this sense that I think the question here is a category error; it's attempting to unify two conceptual systems whose essence is to separate the concepts.

As a final note, I think you may be misunderstanding the ASN.1 concept of `SEQUENCE`, which is different from a `SEQUENCE OF`. A `SEQUENCE` is, roughly speaking, an abstraction of something like a C `struct`; it's a single composite type with named members. It's not a repetition. if you want to express the concept of an ordered list of objects of the same type, you use a `SEQUENCE OF`, which is vaguely similar to a C array, although the length constraints can be a lot more flexible.

`SET` and `SET OF` are the same, except that they are *unordered*. I don't know of any language which implements anything resembling an ASN.1 `SET`, and I'm not sure what advantage such a thing would have. But `SET OF` types certainly exist in many languages, where they're usually called things like "unordered multiset". (Again, ASN.1 allows a the specification of complex constraints on particular `SET OF` objects. A common use case is representing a mapping type as a `SET OF` two-element `SEQUENCE`s.

ASN.1 also has a `CHOICE` composite type, which (like a C++ `std::variant`) represents a single object of one of a specified list of types.

One of the interesting features of ASN.1 is that it allows recursive definitions (although it disallows infinite concrete objects, so the recursive element needs to be optional or inside a possibly empty `SEQUENCE OF`/`SET OF` composite. Recursive definitions at least open the possibility of non-regular grammars.

ASN.1 tools build serializers (generators) and deserializers (parsers) from a set of ASN.1 descriptions. There are a large variety of representation schemes which can be used, and most of them require a more complex syntax than might be apparent from the Abstract Syntax defined in ASN.1. For example, in BER sequence-of objects and character strings can be transparently represented either by preceding the elements with a precise length, or as a series of subsequence chunks followed by an "end-of-sequence" sentinel. Even integers are preceded by a length indicator, since an unconstrained ASN.1 integer does not have a size limit. (The ASN.1 definition can apply a constraint, and some representation schemes use this constraint to simplify the concrete representation.)

X.509 certificates are serialized using the DER representation, which was designed to eliminate encoding options. The intent of DER is to create a one-to-one mapping between each representable value and a bit-vector which can be transmitted. Some aspects of DER are very difficult (if not impossible) to write in a context-free grammar, starting with the requirement that variable-length bit vectors be preceded by their length. Even more complicated is the DER requirement for transmitting `SET-OF` composites: the elements in the `SET-OF` must be individual encoded, and then the encodings are output in lexicographic bit ordering.

The point of a canonical representation such as DER, by the way, is precisely to make it possibly to digitally sign a serialised datum.

In my opinion, ASN.1 is a fascinating and lamentably undervalued body of work. Although it seems unlikely that it will every enjoy a revival (but, then, who knows?), much less that there will ever be an ASN.2, the astonishing range of issues considered in the design of ASN.1 elucidates the complex task of reliably transmitting serialized data in a way that could have immensely benefited the design of other "simpler" serialization technologies.

Comment: 1. Can you add notes whether the following are non-terminals, which I think they are: INTEGER, OBJECT IDENTIFIER, Time/UTCTime/GeneralizedTime and BOOLEAN. Those are only the types mentioned by x509 grammar: https://github.com/TrenchBoot/linux/blob/master/crypto/asymmetric_keys/x509.asn1
2. Can you add link to the Chomskyian grammar paper?
3. So grammars are different from the ASN.1 notation, so parser algorithms used by grammars do not apply here. Which algorithms can we use to parse ASN.1 notation (looking only for names, no need for description - I know recursive descent is good one).

Comment: @eleanor: As I tried to indicate, trying to analyse ASN.1 definition consisting of terminals and non-terminals is misleading at best. In a concrete syntax, it will depends, at least partly, on the concrete encoding you're going to use. In particular in BER and DER values have integer tags, so it's pretty difficult for any value to be a terminal. It doesn't matter, because nobody parses a DER-encoded sequence with a context-free parser.

Comment: @eleanor: 2. The key Chomsky papers are linked from the [Wikipedia entry on the Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), also worth reading.

Comment: @eleanor: 3. Parsing ASN.1 is a very different task from using an ASN.1 description to parse an encoded input stream. You need to keep the two tasks separate. They are in different universes. ASN.1 definitions can be parsed with a context-free grammar, but writing the grammar is not trivial. (I don't have one handy but I wrote one 20 years ago and ended up tearing my hair out trying to get the details right.) To parse a serialized DER data stream for a particular protocol, use a parser generated by an ASN.1 tool. There's no such thing as a general purpose DER parser.

Comment: There is an XML encoding representation, and there is a value representation used in the ASN.1 definition itself (for example, to represent default values). Those can be parsed with recursive descent, but you'll need the ASN.1 definition to make sense of the result.

Comment: As an example of the difference between parsing a syntax notation and parsing a concrete input stream, consider the BNF representation of a context-sensitive grammar. That's a regular language, as it turns out (although that's not the parser I would use). It's not a contradiction that you can parser a the representation of a context-sensitive grammar (not a sentence in a context-sensitive language) using a regular parser.

Comment: "To parse a serialized DER data stream for a particular protocol, use a parser generated by an ASN.1 tool". I'm trying to parse the x509 certificate (binary data and not the actual grammar) but I would like to determine what kind of algorithm would be best to use - what do the parsers generated by an ASN.1 tools use and what tools are those?

Comment: @eleanor: A DER stream is a sequence of tag/length/value triples. So you need to start with a lexical framework which knows how to take those apart. From there, you could use recursive descent, since the stream is basically a preorder traverse of the object. Unfortunately, free ASN.1 tools are a bit scarce, although I haven't looked for one for a long time. I think there's a free online trial of the [OSS Nokalva tool](https://www.oss.com/) if you want to see what these tools look like. That's not an endorsement, which would be against SO rules.

Comment: If I want to extract something from the binary stream (conforming to the above grammar, let's say a field from the X509 certificate), can any of the following types of parsers be used for that: LL, SLR, LR, LALR. I mean just the parser type, I can find the algorithms conforming the type myself.

Comment: "So you need to start with a lexical framework which knows how to take those apart." So basically I would first need to take apart each element and make a tree of elements, each node representing an object (INTEGER, OBJECT IDENTIFIER, etc).

Comment: How hard would it be to generate a parser for X509 above by using a parser generated by ANTLR, something like https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/asn/asn/ASN.g4  (is it even possible)?

Comment: @eleanor: I guess that depends on how comfortable you are with ANTLR. You'd definitely want to write a custom lexer, which raises the ante a bit. Standard language parsers aren't very helpful for parsing binary protocols, particularly ones with explicit lengths.

Comment: Note that the grammar you link to is for parsing an ASN.1 description, not a serialized data stream.